# Dual Monitor, Dual Actions

Tags: windows-7, display, multiple-monitors

I have a simple dual monitor setup, and I need to use to very similar programs simultaneously. For instance, if I click on program1 which is on one monitor1, it will simultaneously click on the other program2 which is on monitor2.

Is there anyway to mirror the actions of one monitor to the other? Any pointers/help would be greatly appreciated. A link for a program that does this would be awesome!

My OS is Windows 7, and the two programs I am using are ArcGis and Mapviewer that both read similar maps.

UPDATE: Thanks to Julian Knight's suggestion, here is the autohotkey script I have come up with:

```
LButton::        ; press alt+k to activate
CoordMode, Mouse, Relative
WinActivate, Partner
Click down 500, 500
WinActivate, Test Electric - ArcMap
Click down 500, 500
return

Escape::  
ExitApp
Return
```

After running this script however, i merely get two clicks at those two points(500,500) on each window. I would like to be able to click and drag both windows simultaneously. Any suggestions?

Comment: Windows, Linux.....??? Improve your post.

Comment: There are dozens upon dozens of software solutions that will do that.   Which tools have you tried and ruled out as not being a solution? This same software is how people run two versions of the same application and perform the same actions twice.

Comment: i have not tried any...many of them cost money, which I simply don't have to spend on a program. Do you know of a free one?

Comment: Your question is confusing.  If both programs are on monitor 2, what does dual monitors have to do with the question?  What are you trying to mirror on the other monitor?

Comment: @fixer1234 - He just wants to control both applications and send mouse i/o commands to both application windows, his description, is more complicated the it needs to be

Comment: @ Ramhound yes that is correct, thanks for bearing with me.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you would need an application that sent scroll commands to both windows simultaneously.

I am not aware of any application on any platform that would do this natively. However, on Windows you could use something like AutoHotKey to set up a hotkey combination that would send a scroll command to both windows as long as you could identify the two windows (AHK and similar applications have tools that help with this).

Further help is not possible without knowing more about the OS and applications you are using.

UPDATE: Now we know the OS is Windows, I can suggest something like AutoHotKey.

That is able to send mouse and/or keyboard clicks to specific windows in specific places. So you could create a macro that, for example, sends page-down keyboard "clicks" to each application window. It comes with a "spy" tool that lets you easily find out the technical identifiers for specific application windows so that you can send the commands to the right place.

If the applications don't support keyboard scrolling, you would have to do it via mouse clicks which is also possible. In that case, however, you need to know the size and position of the windows so that you can successfully "click" on the right bit of the window to scroll.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Julian Knight. my OS is windows 7 and the two programs I am using are ArcGis and a Mapviewer program. The ArcGis is for editing, the mapviewer is just for viewing, but they both view similar maps.

Comment: Thanks for recommending Autohotkey, very useful but I am a bit of a noob. After some research, what I have come up with is in the UPDATE of the OP. Any help would be awesome!